# gnu/screen: session-name in status-line

Tags: gnu-screen

How do I add the GNU/Screen's session-name (as set by `C-a :sessionname foo`) to its' status line?

[The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes) says that `S` is the escape code for *session name* but when I try to add `%S` to my caption I get `0S` instead of `foo`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding `%S` to your hardstatus line should work like you expect. I guess you have made an error in your .screenrc. Maybe you want to post it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [@bjanssen](/users/300566/bjanssen)'s comment, I investigated further and found that:

- On *RHEL 4.8* with Screen version `4.00.02 (FAU) 5-Dec-03`, it prints `0S`.
- On *RHEL 6.4* with Screen version `4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`, it prints nothing.
- On *openSUSE 13.3* with Screen version `4.00.04devel (GNU) 8-Jun-12`, it prints `foo` - the correct result.

And indeed according to the [ChangeLog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/ChangeLog):

```
Version 4.1.0 (??/??/20??):
  ...
  .screenrc:
    ...
    * '%S' in caption/hardstatus string expands to the session name.
```

mystery solved.

Comment: Thanks. The gnu-screen shipped on my OSX 10.8.5 is also 4.00.03